# Locale support in database

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my MySQL database, I store in the table `s_p` (id, name, prod_id) the data in English, and in another table `s_p_l`(id,prod_id,name,locale) additionally the localized names of the products, if available.

At the moment I use

```
SELECT name FROM s_p_l WHERE prod_id=2 AND locale="de_DE";
```

to first check if I have a localized name for product #2, then if this returns no rows,

```
SELECT name FROM s_p WHERE prod_id=2;
```

to get the English name.

How do I now fetch in one query, given the product ID and the locale, the localized product name with the English one as fallback?

(Yes, I use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections)

Comment: can you give samples with desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a left outer join. Select from your `s_p` table (since you know the value will be there), but do a left outer join to your `s_p_l` table. If there's no `s_p_l` record, you'll just get nulls for the `s_p_l` columns, but you'll still get all the matching rows from `s_p`.

```
SELECT
  s_p_l.name AS localizedName,
  s_p.name as fallbackName
FROM
  s_p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN s_p_l ON
    s_p_l.prod_id = s_p.prod_id AND
    s_p_l.locale = "de_DE"
WHERE s_p.prod_id = 2
```

You could probably even change the SELECT to just return one column: `SELECT ISNULL(s_p_l.name, s_p.name)`. (My background is in SQL Server, but I think this is standard SQL that should work on mySQL.)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `UNION` as well.

```
SELECT name FROM s_p_l WHERE prod_id=2 AND locale="de_DE"
union
SELECT name FROM s_p WHERE prod_id=2;
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb9b5/1/0)**

---

EDIT

In case you don't want the English value to be shown if it is present in the local language (`s_p_l`), then use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT name FROM s_p_l WHERE prod_id=2 AND locale="de_DE"
   UNION
   SELECT name FROM s_p WHERE prod_id=2) b
LIMIT 1
;
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2b66/1/0)**

Comment: @user1933738 Your link contains the same data, query and output as my link. The result seems correct. Can you tell me what is wrong, so I can help you?

Comment: I changed the data for s_p_l to (1, 1, 'dename1', 'de_DE'),(3, 3, 'dename3', 'de_DE'), (4, 4, 'dename4', 'de_DE') and the resulting row is still "name2"

Comment: @user1933738 Yes, that is because `prod_id=2` is not present in `s_p_l` and it takes the English value `name2` only.

Comment: @user1933738 There you go. Have added the value for `prod_id=2` in `s_p_l` and the desired result. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7028/4/0